# How to keep the view of VSCode unchanged

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you see,when I touch the file in the left,It gets big and covers most of the views,but I just want it to keep the original view,what should I do? [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the size of the smallest editor group (1px enough) with draggable sash between them and it will stop being smart.